# How to execute Javascript in front of the page Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

Been trying to run different js scripts on Wordpress in front of the page itself but everytime I try, it ends up creating a specific div with given width and height which stays on top of the page.

I was hoping the script itself would run "over" any div on page as an animated effect (on mouse move)
This is particularly one of the scripts I would like to run through all the pages:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <style>
  html, body {
 font-family: 'Play', sans-serif;
 background: #2b2b2b;
 margin: 0;
}

#info {
 position: absolute;
 left: 10px;
 top: 10px;
}

#info {
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 padding: 12px 10px;
 margin-bottom: 1px;
 color: #fff;
}

#info h1 {
 line-height: 22px;
 font-weight: 300;
 font-size: 18px;
 margin: 0;
}

#info h2 {
 line-height: 14px;
 font-weight: 300;
 font-size: 12px;
 color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
 margin: 0 0 6px 0;
}

#info a {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-decoration: none;
 border-bottom: 1px dotted rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
 margin-right: 4px;
 line-height: 20px;
 font-size: 10px;
 color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}

#info a:hover {
 border-bottom: 1px dotted rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
 color: rgba(255,255,255,1.0);
}
  </style>
  
</head>

<body>

  
<div id="container"></div>
  <script src='https://rawgithub.com/soulwire/sketch.js/v1.0/js/sketch.min.js'></script>

  

    <script>
 
function Particle( x, y, radius ) {
 this.init( x, y, radius );
}

Particle.prototype = {

 init: function( x, y, radius ) {

  this.alive = true;

  this.radius = radius || 10;
  this.wander = 0.15;
  this.theta = random( TWO_PI );
  this.drag = 0.92;
  this.color = '#fff';

  this.x = x || 0.0;
  this.y = y || 0.0;

  this.vx = 0.0;
  this.vy = 0.0;
 },

 move: function() {

  this.x += this.vx;
  this.y += this.vy;

  this.vx *= this.drag;
  this.vy *= this.drag;

  this.theta += random( -0.5, 0.5 ) * this.wander;
  this.vx += sin( this.theta ) * 0.1;
  this.vy += cos( this.theta ) * 0.1;

  this.radius *= 0.96;
  this.alive = this.radius > 0.5;
 },

 draw: function( ctx ) {

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc( this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, TWO_PI );
  ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
  ctx.fill();
 }
};

// ----------------------------------------
// Example
// ----------------------------------------

var MAX_PARTICLES = 280;
var COLOURS = [ '#69D2E7', '#A7DBD8', '#E0E4CC', '#F38630', '#FA6900', '#FF4E50', '#F9D423' ];

var particles = [];
var pool = [];

var demo = Sketch.create({
 container: document.getElementById( 'container' )
});

demo.setup = function() {

 // Set off some initial particles.
 var i, x, y;

 for ( i = 0; i < 20; i++ ) {
  x = ( demo.width * 0.5 ) + random( -100, 100 );
  y = ( demo.height * 0.5 ) + random( -100, 100 );
  demo.spawn( x, y );
 }
};

demo.spawn = function( x, y ) {

 if ( particles.length >= MAX_PARTICLES )
  pool.push( particles.shift() );

 particle = pool.length ? pool.pop() : new Particle();
 particle.init( x, y, random( 5, 40 ) );

 particle.wander = random( 0.5, 2.0 );
 particle.color = random( COLOURS );
 particle.drag = random( 0.9, 0.99 );

 theta = random( TWO_PI );
 force = random( 2, 8 );

 particle.vx = sin( theta ) * force;
 particle.vy = cos( theta ) * force;

 particles.push( particle );
}

demo.update = function() {

 var i, particle;

 for ( i = particles.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {

  particle = particles[i];

  if ( particle.alive ) particle.move();
  else pool.push( particles.splice( i, 1 )[0] );
 }
};

demo.draw = function() {

 demo.globalCompositeOperation  = 'lighter';
 
 for ( var i = particles.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
  particles[i].draw( demo );
 }
};

demo.mousemove = function() {

 var particle, theta, force, touch, max, i, j, n;

 for ( i = 0, n = demo.touches.length; i < n; i++ ) {

  touch = demo.touches[i], max = random( 1, 4 );
  for ( j = 0; j < max; j++ ) demo.spawn( touch.x, touch.y );
 }
};
 </script>




</body>

</html>
```

I would like the particles to run through the site.

Any help with it?

Answer (score 0):

First I would start by making sure you properly enqueue the your javascript and css:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts

> wp_enqueue_scripts is the proper hook to use when enqueuing items that
>   are meant to appear on the front end.

Comment: I'm quite sure I managed it working. But the problem is that the js itself creates a canvas.
I tried running the canvas as overlay using z-index,but then I can't click ahrefs underlying :/